# Join new Azure VM to domain: reboot needed?

Tags: json, powershell, azure

I'm creating a VM on Azure using Powershell and a JSON template. The template includes [this bit](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/364dcf26ce48f93692e2c9c0fc3f85f2d73c43ce/201-vm-domain-join/azuredeploy.json) so that the join operation should be part of the provisioning operation.

But our network dept. says we need to restart the new machine to be sure it's properly joined. Thus my questions:

- *When* exactly is the join operation conducted?
- *Do* we actually need to reboot the new VM (or is it somehow part of provisioning and therefore *not* needed)?
- *How* can I make a new VM reboot as part of provisioning (ideally, using another JSON snippet)?

**Update:** Here's the relevant snippet. Notice there is a `"Restart": "true"` part, this is what I'm unsure about.

```
{
    "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'),'/joindomain')]",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "dependsOn": ["[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('vmName'))]"],
    "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
        "type": "JsonADDomainExtension",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.0",
        "settings": {
            "Name": "[parameters('domainToJoin')]",
            "OUPath": "[parameters('ouPath')]",
            "User": "[concat(parameters('domainToJoin'), '\\', parameters('domainUsername'))]",
            "Restart": "true",
            "Options": "[parameters('domainJoinOptions')]"
        },
        "protectedsettings": {
            "Password": "[parameters('domainPassword')]"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have got `"Restart": "true"` set, then you can consider them rebooted once you are able to log in.

The process should be that the machine is provisioned, it is logged into and has its username / password set. Then any further extensions are run. Including the domain join one.

If the domain join script is set to restart then it will do so once joined. You should be able to see this if you look through the deployment log.

Comment: So I can count on each extension being run in order, with reboots and stuff done as appropriate?

Comment: @KlaymenDK that is probably something that needs some testing! I'm intrigued by the answer now though (maybe worth a separate question)

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested this myself with a couple of extensions (Is Bicep extensions but compiles into Json anyways.

**Recommendation:**
If you are deploying many extensions or have other jobs to perform after adding them deactivate restart from 'JoinDomain' Extensions. It leads to unforeseeable errors. In my case, my TeamServicesAgent was reporting an error because it took longer than expected to connect to my deployment group, then the joinDomain extension succeeded and by the time this happen i Received a log error from VstsAgent saying that:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007045B): A system shutdown is in progress. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007045B)
```

It took me a lot to realize that actually the domainjoin extension was doing so.

Did it by filtering event viewer logs from the virtual machine

```
41,1074,1076,6005,6006,6008,6009,6013
```

```json
  resource IaaSAntimalware_ext 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions@2023-03-01' = [for vmName in vmNames: {
  name: '${vmName}/IaaSAntimalware'
  location: location
  tags: {
    CostAllocationCode: 'TOBESPECIFIED'
    CostAllocationType: 'TOBESPECIFIED'
    Environment: 'TOBESPECIFIED'
  }
  properties: {
    autoUpgradeMinorVersion: true
    publisher: 'Microsoft.Azure.Security'
    type: 'IaaSAntimalware'
    typeHandlerVersion: '1.3'
    settings: {
      AntimalwareEnabled: true
      RealtimeProtectionEnabled: 'true'
      ScheduledScanSettings: {
        isEnabled: 'false'
        day: '7'
        time: '120'
        scanType: 'Quick'
      }
    }
  }
}]

resource TeamServicesAgent_ext 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions@2023-03-01' = [for vmName in vmNames: {
  name: '${vmName}/TeamServicesAgent'
  location: location
  properties: {
    publisher: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services'
    type: 'TeamServicesAgent'
    typeHandlerVersion: '1.0'
    autoUpgradeMinorVersion: true
    enableAutomaticUpgrade: true
    settings: {
      VSTSAccountName: 'https://<organization>.visualstudio.com/'
      TeamProject: '<team project>'
      DeploymentGroup: deploymentGroup
      AgentName: vmName
    }
    protectedSettings: {
      PATToken: PAT
    }
  }
}]

resource DomainJoin_ext 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions@2023-03-01' = [for vmName in vmNames: {
  name: '${vmName}/joindomain'
  location: location
  properties: {
    publisher: 'Microsoft.Compute'
    type: 'JsonADDomainExtension'
    typeHandlerVersion: '1.3'
    autoUpgradeMinorVersion: true
    settings: {
      name: domainToJoin
      ouPath: ouPath
      user: domainUsername
      restart: false
      options: domainJoinOptions
    }
    protectedSettings: {
      Password: domainPassword
    }
  }
}]
```